# Underscore/Backbone Templates .get

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Is it possible to use `.get('property')` in an **underscore/backbone** template?

Example:

Passing data to the template:

```
var pageTemplate = _.template( PageTemplate, this);
$(this.el).html(pageTemplate);
```

The template it's self:

```
 <div id="productContainer" style="left:<%= 1 + (450 - model.get('previewHeight'))/2 %>px;"></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this really the same as your last question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible.

```
var my_json = {};
my_json.model = my_model;

var html_template = _.template($("#my_template").html());
$(this.el).html(html_template(my_json));

<div id="my_template" style="left:<%= 1 + (450 - model.get('previewHeight'))/2 %>px;"></div>
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you!